# My pocket watch is not visible through it's glass except

Tags: objects, normals

I am using eevee and blender v2.93.3. My pocket watch glass uses a glass bsdf that works but nothing other than the hands appear, not even the body itself.

[image: Pocket watch without glass]

[image: Pocket watch with glass]

After looking at the normals, it appears that my watch body has no normals. The watch body and face image are the only objects not using a principled bsdf.

I have tried to recalculate normals inside and outside and flip normals, add a solidify modifier to my watch body but nothing has worked so far.

[image]

Here are the nodes for my watch body and face if it helps.

[image: Watch body material]

[image: Watch face material]

**-----Update:-----**

I forgot to add in a photo of the node I used for my glass so here it is. It's really just a glass bsdf.

[image: Original Setup]

I tried changing it based on Christopher's suggestion but the problem seems to persist.
[image: Glass with principled bsdf]

Comment: That seems to be a strange node setup - firstly, image textures usually use UV texture coordinates. Also (although I cannot see it in your graph), you mentioned you are using a glass bsdf and eevee - glass bsdf is meant for cycles, use a principled bsdf with transmission set to 1 and roughness lowered instead. Make sure to the set the Material's Blend Mode to something other than _opaque_ (alpha-blend should work).

Comment: I just started learning blender not too long ago and followed some tutorials to make this so sorry if it's weird. I'll try your method.

How do you determine which node works for which rendering engine?

Comment: Blender has come a long way in terms of making all nodes "work" for both engines, but due to the difference in renderers, some things don't translate well. Transparency is one of them and the glass bsdf took the biggest hit (although they have begun to re-optimize it for eevee in the most recent releases). It still doesn't look quite right, so the convention for eevee for glass is still transmission 1, roughness ~0.

Comment: Ah I see, guess I'll need to read up on what works and doesn't then, thanks for the info. Also, I tried your method but the problem seems to persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some checking, the problem is actually **screen space reflection** being turned on for both the body and watch face which makes it transparent through the glass.

Answer (score 0):

This happens as hands are separate objects. Your glass should be an **extra face**, as is the inset in the example below.
[image]

Besides, you write 'glass' but put no Glass or at least Transparent shader node. And in your node setup you connected Color and Fac sockets which is **wrong** as Fac is non-color data and cannot be connected with Color. Also Shader goes exclusively with BSDF. Color connects **only** to Color. And Diffuse shader goes **just before** Output. Do some reading before you start using nodes.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included the node for the glass as well because it's not in the post so I'll add it in. For the extra face, did you mean I should extrude another face and make it glass and not a separate object?

Also, for the node socket, I just had a read of the official documentation and they are apparently all valid connections because the data they are implicitly converted under the hood like color data being converted to greyscale (color -> fac).

Comment: @Tengo 4390: in your case select the rim circle edges, make a face and apply glass  to it.

Comment: Just tried your method and the problem still persisted but I have found that the problem was screen space reflection being turned on for both the body and watch. Thanks for the help and useful info though.